# fs.copyFile is not a function

Tags: node.js

Estou tentando manipular arquivos com o NodeJS, utilizando o `fs.copyFile` em meu servidor (Debian Jessie), mas eu não consigo copiar arquivos. Eu já fiz de tudo pra tentar solucionar o problema, já até copiei exatamente o exemplo dado na documentação e repliquei os arquivos, mas é sempre o mesmo erro que é retornado (inclusive utilizando o `fs.copyFileSync`).

O erro apresentado é o `TypeError: fs.copyFile is not a function`, e não aparece nenhuma informação adicional sobre ele.

Meu código:

```
const fs = require('fs');

fs.copyFile('/home/savi/teste1.txt', '/home/savi/teste2.txt', (err) => {
    if(!err){
        console.log("Copiou");
    }
});
```

Comment: Qual o retorno de `console.log(fs)`?

Comment: Acabei de descobrir que, como eu pesquisei um termo genérico no google pra achar a documentação do nodejs a respeito da cópia de arquivos, ele me retornou a página de documentação da versão v8.6 e não da v6.11.3 que eu estou utilizando, e com certeza esse é o erro. A função fs.copyFile só existe na versão v8.6. ;-;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A funcionalidade `fs.copyFile` foi adicionada só na versão `8.5` do Node.
Era muito esperada pois não havia uma API simples para copiar ficheiros antes.

Vendo [na documentação está lá](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_copyfile_src_dest_flags_callback):

> Added in: v8.5.0